# can we use "prompt" function of javascript in pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

can we use "prompt" function of javascript in pentaho? I am getting this error

> JavaScript - ERROR (version 7.0.0.0-25, build 1 from 2016-11-05
>   15.35.36 by buildguy) : Couldn't compile javascript: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "prompt" is not
>   defined. (#1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pentaho Data Integration uses Mozilla's Rhino engine. If the function isn't part of that engine, then you won't be able to use it.